# If $p$ is an odd prime that does not divide $a$, show that $a^{\frac {p-1}2}\equiv \pm 1 \pmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $p$ is an odd prime that  does not divide $a$, show that: $$a^{\frac {p-1}2}\equiv \pm1 \pmod p$$

We are just learning congruence in my class, so this might be trivial to some of you but can someone help explain this to me. Can someone help me get started. I think you might have to use Fermat's theorem. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Sure...what happens when you square $a^{\frac {p-1}2} \pmod p$?

Comment: If you square that then you get Fermat's theorem I'm pretty sure.

Comment: Well, you get $a^{p-1}$ and you can then invoke Fermat to deduce that this is $1\pmod p$.

Comment: Okay thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Fermat's theorem, you have $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. Thus, $p\mid a^{p-1}-1=(a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}-1)(a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}+1)$, and thus, either $p\mid a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}-1$ or $p\mid a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}+1$, which is the claim.